# Get current month date in date components

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

I am getting NSDateComponents of date `2018-06-01 00:00:00 +0000` like this

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitYear |NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute fromDate:date];
[components setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation: @"UTC"]];
 NSInteger month =[components month];
```

When I print the value of components , I get this value.

```
    TimeZone: GMT (GMT) offset 0
    Calendar Year: 2018
    Month: 5
    Leap month: no
    Day: 31
    Hour: 21
    Minute: 0
```

My expected out put should be

```
    TimeZone: GMT (GMT) offset 0
    Calendar Year: 2018
    Month: 6
    Leap month: no
    Day: 1
    Hour: 0
    Minute: 0
```

How can I get the value of month correctly?

Comment: You are trying to get the components of "now". Do you want "now" in the user's local time or do you want the "now" in UTC time?

Comment: @rmaddy What makes you think he is talking about "now"? Obviously `date` represents some date around 2018-06-01.

Comment: @AndréSlotta OK, maybe not "now" but some `date` that has already been obtained.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `NSCalendar components:fromDate:` the results are based on the calendar's current timezone which defaults to the user's local timezone.

Your attempt to set the resulting components' `timeZone` doesn't alter the current components. That would only affect how the components would be interpreted if you used the components to create a new `NSDate`.

Assuming your goal is to get the components of `date` in UTC time and not in local time, then you need to set the calendar's `timeZone` before getting the components from `date`.

```
NSDate *date = // your date
NSCalendar *calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar;
calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute fromDate:date];
NSLog(@"UTC Components: %@", components);
```

But keep in mind that you must understand which timezone you really want here. Be sure you really want the UTC timezone. Don't use UTC just because it matches the output of `NSLog(@"Date: %@", date);`. That log shows the date in UTC time.

Comment: Great , it is working fine now. Great answer @rmaddy.

Answer (score 0):

How do you create your initial `date` object? When I try that setup everything works as expected:

```
NSString *dateString = @"2018-06-01 00:00:00 +0000";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z";
dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSCalendar *calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar;
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute fromDate:date];

NSLog(@"Before: %@", components);
/*
 Before: <NSDateComponents: 0x604000158e10>
 Calendar Year: 2018
 Month: 6
 Leap month: no
 Day: 1
 Hour: 2
 Minute: 0
 */

components.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];

NSLog(@"After: %@", components);
/*
 After: <NSDateComponents: 0x604000158e10>
 TimeZone: GMT (GMT) offset 0
 Calendar Year: 2018
 Month: 6
 Leap month: no
 Day: 1
 Hour: 2
 Minute: 0
 */
```

Comment: The question is tagged Objective-C, not Swift. Please post answers in the correct language. And the question has nothing to do with date formatting and converting strings to dates.

Comment: @rmaddy Updated my answer to Obj-C. I do not agree with your second point though since this **could** actually be the problem in my opinion.

Comment: OK but your answer is still wrong and it still doesn't do anything differently than the original code.

Comment: @rmaddy I think the source `date` object could be the problem. That's why I added the correct date conversion to my answer.

Comment: No, the source date has nothing to do with the question or the issue.

Comment: I don't have any more arguments. Maybe the answer helps, maybe it does not. :)

Answer (score -4):

You need to get the last month date first.

```
extension Date {

   //it will give the date of last month
   var previousMonthDate: Date {
      return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: self)!
   } 
}
```

Get the date components from date

```
let dt = Date()
let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: dt.previousMonthDate)
print(components.day ?? 0)
print(components.month ?? 0)
print(components.year ?? 0)
```

Comment: Why to get previous month date?

Comment: @HimanDhawan Actually the title you chose is kinda misleading. Sounds like `Getting previous month date` is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question.